# Best way to create an array from an object that has number of copies

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

From an object like this:

```
{a:1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

I would like to turn into

```
['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

Where the key is the string and the value is the number of copies, order doesn't matter.

What's the best way to do this?

I was thinking about using array.fill but not sure if that's actually easier than just iterating and push.

Edit: Currently this:

```
const arr = []
_.each(obj, function (v, k) {
  _.times(v, function () {
    arr.push(k)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) an array of each size.

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const result = Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => Array(v).fill(k));

console.log(result)
```

or with Lodash

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const arr = _.flatMap(obj, (v,k) => Array(v).fill(k))

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But there's nothing like a simple loop

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
const result = []

for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  while (v--) {
    result.push(k)
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks though I think this is slower than just a push.

Comment: didn't test, but it does create a new array for each property so likely. I'm happy with the push, though I'd probably just use two loops. ('Best' is generally a poor descriptor in a question like this, do you mean most readable? most efficient on large data sets? fewest characters? no external libraries?)

Comment: Yeah I agree best wasn't specific enough. I wasn't thinking too hard about criteria just wanted to see what other options there were.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Array#reduce` as follows:

```js
const input = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3};

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce(
    (prev, [key,value]) => prev.concat( Array(value).fill(key) ),
    []
);

console.log( output );
```

Or, using `Array#push` instead of `Array#concat`,

```js
const input = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3};

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce(
    (prev, [key,value]) => prev.push( ...Array(value).fill(key) ) && prev,
    []
);

console.log( output );
```

Or, using `for` loops,

```js
const input = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3};

const output = [],
      pairs = Object.entries(input);
for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    const [key, value] = pairs[i];
    for(let j = 0; j < value; j++) {
        output.push( key );
    }
}

console.log( output );
```

Comment: I'm going to give this one the win for being the fastest substantially, thanks.

Comment: actually replacing the `concat` with a push is still faster in quick testing. `(prev, [key, value]) => (prev.push(...Array(value).fill(key)), prev),` (but nested `for` loops are faster still ;))

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the object into an array of keys using `Object.keys` and then use a newly created empty results array, then map through the keys.

For each key I would add a fill array to the existing results.

Here's the ES6 solution to that (no extra libraries required)

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
let result = []
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  result = [...result, ...new Array(obj[key]).fill(key)]
})

console.log(result)
```